# Java - How to check an existing user in the database (for a signup interface)?

Tags: java, mysql, servlets, dao

So here's what I've done so far. it is also already connected to the database with the username as the primary key.

```
protected void processRequest(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
        throws ServletException, IOException {
    response.setContentType("text/html;charset=UTF-8");
    try {
        Accounts bean = new Accounts();
        bean.setUsername(request.getParameter("uname"));
        bean.setName(request.getParameter("fname"));
        bean.setEmail(request.getParameter("email"));
        bean.setPassword(request.getParameter("password"));
        AccountsDAO aO = new AccountsDAO();
        aO.addAccount(bean);
        response.sendRedirect("Stream.jsp");
    }
    finally{

    }
}
```

what i want is, when i try to register an account with the same username/email of any existing user in the database, it will redirect to another with another page also using a response.sendRedireect("file.jsp"); that will require the user to register again with another username/email. Thank you in advance!

here is my AccountsDAO

```
public void addAccount(Accounts bean) {
    try {
        bConnector = new DBConnector();
        Connection c = bConnector.getConnection();
        String query = "insert into account (username, name, email, password) values (?,?,?,?)";
        PreparedStatement preparedstatement = c.prepareStatement(query);
        preparedstatement.setString(1, bean.getUsername());
        preparedstatement.setString(2, bean.getName());
        preparedstatement.setString(3, bean.getEmail());
        preparedstatement.setString(4, bean.getPassword());
        preparedstatement.executeUpdate();
    } catch (SQLException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(AccountsDAO.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }
}
```

Comment: post your `AccountsDAO` class to get more specific answer

Comment: have you tried it ? if it solved your issue accept the answer as it will help others

Comment: i'll just add the catch statement in my existing servlet?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Once you have `username` as primary it will not allow to insert duplicates . so try like this

```
try
{
//query to insert your username which you get from user
}
```

If it is duplicate it will throw an exception as `ora-` so handle the exception using page redirect using catch block.

```
catch(Exception e)
{
system.out.print(e);
response.sendRedirect("file.jsp");
}
```

**Update**

Declare an `integer` variable to check whether you have inserted the value . Also change the return type of the method `addAccount(Accounts bean)` to `int`

```
public int addAccount(Accounts bean) {

    int count=0; 
    try {
        bConnector = new DBConnector();
        Connection c = bConnector.getConnection();
        String query = "insert into account (username, name, email, password) values (?,?,?,?)";
        PreparedStatement preparedstatement = c.prepareStatement(query);
        preparedstatement.setString(1, bean.getUsername());
        preparedstatement.setString(2, bean.getName());
        preparedstatement.setString(3, bean.getEmail());
        preparedstatement.setString(4, bean.getPassword());
        count=preparedstatement.executeUpdate();
    } catch (SQLException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(AccountsDAO.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }
 return count;
}
```

In your servlet,

```
int count=0;
try {
        Accounts bean = new Accounts();
        bean.setUsername(request.getParameter("uname"));
        bean.setName(request.getParameter("fname"));
        bean.setEmail(request.getParameter("email"));
        bean.setPassword(request.getParameter("password"));
        AccountsDAO aO = new AccountsDAO();
        count=aO.addAccount(bean);
        if(count>0){
        response.sendRedirect("Stream.jsp"); \\Success condition here
        }
        else{
         response.sendRedirect("file.jsp");   \\ failure condition here
       }
    }
    catch(Exception e)
{
system.out.print(e);
}
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: it says that e is an unused variable. sorry i'm really not yet knowledgeable about this.

Comment: there's an error in the servlet at line 9 based from your answer, it states "incompatible types: void cannot be converted to int" do i have to change something in my DAOInterface as well?

Comment: Yes of course you need to change the return type in interface as int

Comment: public interface AccountsDAOInterface {
public int addAccount(Accounts bean);
}

where and what to add here in my interface?

Comment: @user3514806 No need i your interface is ok . Any errors now?

Comment: I still have an error here: "count = aO.addAccount(bean);" still the same error, incompatible types. but i already changed the void to int already.

Comment: Lets continue this in [chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/50527/san-created-for-jdbc)

Comment: i'm just a newbie so i don't have 20 reputations yet for me to use the chat.. :(

Comment: Once you made the above changes it should work check for any other places where you have the addAccount method

Comment: @user3514806 notify me if it works or incase you face any issue

Comment: the code you suggested for the servlet is finding a return statement. should i just return count? and is variable e not really used just for the sake of the catch statement?

Comment: OMG OMG OMG OMG OMG OMG OMG IT WORKED. NOW HOW DO I ACCEPT YOUR ANSWER?